# Catkin rosconsole cross-compilation make error

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, catkin, cross-compiling, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm still working towards a cross-compilation of the packages in ros-comm for a Zynq ARM target running Angstrom Linux. I have now run into an issue during the catkin build process with rosconsole.

I'm getting an error while compiling rosconsole.cpp

./src/rosconsole/include/ros/console.h:55 fatal error: log4cxx/logger.h: No such file or directory error

I've set the path to the log4cxx include files directly in my rostoolchain file in the CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH variable. I've also tried setting LOG4CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS. When set in the LOG4CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS variable the directory appears in the flags.make as a -I flag in the CXX_FLAGS.

Any thoughts on what I need to set to fix this?

Thanks,

Marcus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69883/catkin-rosconsole-cross-compilation-make-error/) by [lboltzmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5542/lboltzmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2013-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to get this to work by editing the CMakeLists.txt file and setting the LOG4CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS variable directly. I then verified the same thing works in my rostoolchain file. It was a case of the path being .../include instead of the .../include/log4cxx I had been using.

Now I'm seeing the same error during the build of roscpp. The CMakeLists.txt for roscpp doesn't appear to reference the log4cxx directories or libraries, but I still see the same console.h error referring to logger.h.

Is there a better place to set the include dependency? And if roscpp has a dependency on log4cxx why doesn't it reference the LOG4CXX variables?

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [lboltzmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5542/lboltzmann/) with karma: 38 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The CMakeLists.txt uses pkg-config to find LOG4CXX. Could it be that **liblog4cxx.pc** is missing from your **$PKG_CONFIG_PATH**?

See: https://github.com/strawlab/ros_comm/blob/master/tools/rosconsole/CMakeLists.txt#L38

**UPDATE**: oops! I had failed to notice that the link above is to the wrong repository.

The correct `groovy_devel` version is here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/groovy-devel/tools/rosconsole/CMakeLists.txt#L6

That file uses CMAKE `find_package()` instead of `pkg-config` to locate log4cxx.

Unfortunately, I don't know where that CMake module is supposed to be defined. The Debian `liblog4cxx10-dev` package seems to provide the pkg-config file, but no CMake module.

This may be a bug that only crops up when cross-compiling. I just don't know.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lboltzmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5542/lboltzmann/) on 2013-07-31**:
I'll look into this. I'm just learning about CMake so I'm not sure of the best way to interact with it. Thanks for your suggestion.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-31**:
It's not a CMake thing. What does `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` print? Is there a `liblog4cxx.pc` file in any of those directories?

**Comment by [lboltzmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5542/lboltzmann/) on 2013-08-01**:
echo returns  a blank. My CMakeLists.txt file for rosconsole is quite a bit different then that version (Groovy catkin source version). There isn't a find_package(PkgConfig).  It uses find_package(Log4cxx QUIET) and if it does find the library it looks in the system path only using find_library(LOG4CXX_LIBRARIES log4cxx).

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-08-01**:
What version are you trying to cross-compile? Please be very careful to use the correct sources for the ROS distro you are running.

**Comment by [lboltzmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5542/lboltzmann/) on 2013-08-02**:
I'm cross-compiling groovy source. I followed the source installation instructions for ROS-comm on the wiki. I can build fine if I don't cross as it looks in my system path for the lib and the x86 versions are there.

Thanks.